# Counting specific rows mysql + express

Tags: mysql, sql, express

I have a table like this (which also has other details):

```
order_id    coupon_name
1            XMAS20
2            XMAS20
3            NYE10
4            NYE10
5            XMAS20
```

I want an sql query that returns this(in express):

```
[{ coupon_name: XMAS20, uses: 3 }, { coupon_name: NYE10, uses: 2 }]
```

In sql:

```
coupon_name    uses
XMAS20         3
NYE10          2
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes this worked but the names aren't dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `GROUP BY`, you should get all the `COUPON_NAME` present in your table

```
SELECT COUPON_NAME, COUNT(*) AS USES FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY COUPON_NAME;
```